Problem with height calculation automatically to UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell
Good?
I have a problem with the implementation of a UICollectionview intro a UITableViewCell, because the height calculation of this component does not work properly, even though using updateConstraints() and called by delegate tableView.beginUpdates(), sometimes works correctly and sometimes renders missing height.
correctly render

wrong render

My layout is a table with a lot of cells, these cells have some texts and items in two collectionviews (I'm using UICollectionView because the size of these items needs to be dynamically)
The implementation of the UITableViewCell:
protocol CardTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func updateTableView()
}

class CardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "CardTableViewCell"
    
    lazy var cardView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.separator.cgColor
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var containerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        return stackView
    }()
    
    lazy var title: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var subtitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var sourceNew: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        return label
    }()
    
    var assetsCollectionView: AssetsCollectionView = {
        let collectionView = AssetsCollectionView()
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    lazy var benchmarksCollectionView: BenchmarksCollectionView = {
        let collectionView = BenchmarksCollectionView()
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return collectionView
    }()

    weak var delegate: CardTableViewCellDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Init
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    func configure(with card: Card) {
        title.text = card.title
        subtitle.text = card.subtitle
        sourceNew.text = card.sourceNew
        
        
        configureAssetsCollectionView(with: card.assets)
        configurebenchmarksCollectionView(with: card.benchmarks)
    }
    
    private func configureAssetsCollectionView(with model: [Asset]?) {
        if let assets = model {
            assetsCollectionView.configure(with: assets)
            
            containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(assetsCollectionView)
            
            assetsCollectionView.updateConstraints()
            delegate?.updateTableView()
        }
    }
    
    private func configurebenchmarksCollectionView(with model: [Benchmark]?) {
        if let benchmarks = model {
            benchmarksCollectionView.configure(with: benchmarks)
            
            containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(benchmarksCollectionView)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - ViewCode
extension CardTableViewCell {
    func setupView() {
        setupLayout()
        setupHierarchy()
        setupConstrains()
    }
    
    func setupLayout() {
        backgroundColor = .white
        cardView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    func setupHierarchy() {
        [title,
         subtitle,
         sourceNew].forEach(containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(_:))
        
        cardView.addSubview(containerStackView)
        
        contentView.addSubview(cardView)
    }
    
    func setupConstrains() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            cardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            containerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            
            assetsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 22),
            benchmarksCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 22)
        ])
    }
}

and, the UICollectionView:
import UIKit

class AssetsCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    private var assets: [Asset] = []
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        print(contentSize)
        return self.contentSize
    }
    
    init() {
        let layout = LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
        super.init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        delegate = self
        dataSource = self
        
        register(AssetCollectionViewCell.self,
                 forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AssetCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(with assets: [Asset]) {
        self.assets = assets
        reloadData()
    }
}

extension AssetsCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return assets.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AssetCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? AssetCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        cell.configure(with: assets[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
    }
}

So, can this component calculate your height automatically without using height calculation tricks? I tried using a lot of methods to send the cell to recalculate your constraints, but no one worked. :(
I know that I can use the number of items to calculate the height, but I need more powerful code to handle possible causes... any anyone help me with this?
The github url to reproduce locally: https://github.com/ramonfsk/MarketContextTimeline.git

You may be able to fix this by overriding systemLayoutSizeFitting(...) in your CardTableViewCell class. Difficult to say, because we can't run your code to try it out. If you can put together a [mre], we'll have a better chance of helping.

I tried to use this approach and, the collectionview layout always renders wrong, with a height shorter than it should be  :(
I'll put the github link in the answer, tks ;)

This layout is difficult because collection views don't really "work that way." You say in your post: "I'm using UICollectionView because the size of these items needs to be dynamically" -- are you planning to use any other collection view features? Such as selecting cells? Or, is this only to get the desired layout?

just for the layout, I don't intend to use any other feature except to take advantage of the ease of placing several cells of different sizes automatically adjusting

OK - I've put together another approach for you, using a custom UIView subclass instead of UICollectionView. I will write it up as an answer tomorrow morning.

You'll run into a number of issues trying to use a "self-sizing" collection view.
Collection views are designed to layout the cells based on the frame - not the other way around.
If we look at your LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout (this is what happens whether using a subclassed layout or not):
`layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)`

is called.
If we start the layout with:
assetsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 22)

the rect in layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) will be:
(0.0, 0.0, 353.0, 22.0)  // the width will vary

Let's say we're using these strings:
        "MGLU3", "IBVV11", "BBSA3", "Slightly Longer String",
        "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT",
        "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE",
        "Hash Index Ethereum position replicated with a 100% accuracy",
        "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",

and the goal is this:

The layout starts starts looking like this:

Let's add a red rectangle showing the initial frame:

and a green bracket showing the current collectionView.contentSize.height:

So, let's expand the collection view frame to show all the cells:

Note that the contentSize.height does not reflect all the cells... and it can vary wildly depending on the actual cell sizes, initial frame, etc. We don't get a valid (for our purposes) contentSize.height until all of the cells have been laid-out by the collection view.
Even if we jump through a bunch of hoops to "force" all of the cells to be rendered, we still have timing issues... the collection view can't layout the cells until it knows its width, and since it's embedded in a table view cell we have to make "call-backs" to auto-size the cell heights.
In addition -- let's use your code but explicitly set the height of the collection view to show all the cells:

Looks good -- except cells are reused... so let's scroll up and down a bit:

Yeah, clearly not acceptable.
So... I'd suggest using a UIView subclass that lays-out the labels on its own.
The general logic is:

use .systemLayoutSizeFitting(...) to get the size of the "item"
if it will fit on the current row, set its frame
if it is too wide, move it down a row
if it is the first item on a row, and is still too wide, allow it to word-wrap
after all items have been laid-out, update a height constraint so this view behaves nicely with auto-layout

We'll start with a "padded label view" that is roughly equivalent to a cell:
class PaddedLabelView: UIView {
    
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(theLabel)
        let edgeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -2.0),
        ]
        // this prevents auto-layout complaints
        edgeConstraints[2].priority = .required - 1
        edgeConstraints[3].priority = .required - 1
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(edgeConstraints)

        // properties
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        theLabel.textColor = .white
        theLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)
        backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

and now we create an "arranged views" class:
class BasicArrangedViewsView: UIView {
    
    public var theStrings: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            // remove existing views
            for v in labelViews { v.removeFromSuperview() }
            labelViews = []
            for str in theStrings {
                let t = PaddedLabelView()
                t.theLabel.text = str
                addSubview(t)
                labelViews.append(t)
            }
            calcFrames(bounds.width)
        }
    }
    
    // horizontal space between label views
    let interItemSpace: CGFloat = 8.0
    
    // vertical space between "rows"
    let lineSpace: CGFloat = 8.0
    
    // we use these to set the intrinsic content size
    private var myHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var myWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    private var myHC: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    private var labelViews: [PaddedLabelView] = []
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        // initialize height constraint, but don't activate it yet
        myHC = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        myHC.priority = .required - 1
    }
    
    func calcFrames(_ tagetWidth: CGFloat) {
        // this can be called multiple times, and
        //  may be called before we have a frame
        if tagetWidth == 0.0 {
            return
        }
        
        var newWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
        var newHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        var x: CGFloat = 0.0
        var y: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        var isMultiLine: Bool = false
        var thisRect: CGRect = .zero
        
        for thisView in labelViews {
            // start with NOT needing to wrap
            isMultiLine = false
            // set the frame width to a very wide value, so we get the non-wrapped size
            thisView.frame.size.width = 5000
            thisView.layoutIfNeeded()
            var sz: CGSize = thisView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
            sz.width = ceil(sz.width)
            sz.height = ceil(sz.height)
            thisRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: sz.width, height: sz.height)
            // if this item is too wide to fit on the "row"
            if thisRect.maxX > tagetWidth {
                // if this is not the FIRST item on the row
                //  move down a row and reset x
                if x > 0.0 {
                    x = 0.0
                    y = thisRect.maxY + lineSpace
                }
                thisRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: sz.width, height: sz.height)
                // if this item is still too wide to fit, that means
                //  it needs to wrap the text
                if thisRect.maxX > tagetWidth {
                    isMultiLine = true
                    // this will give us the height based on max available width
                    sz = thisView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: tagetWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
                    sz.width = ceil(sz.width)
                    sz.height = ceil(sz.height)
                    // update the frame
                    thisView.frame.size = sz
                    thisView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    // this will give us the width needed for the wrapped text (instead of the max available width)
                    sz = thisView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
                    sz.width = ceil(sz.width)
                    sz.height = ceil(sz.height)
                    thisRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: sz.width, height: sz.height)
                }
            }
            // if we needed to wrap the text, adjust the next Y and reset X
            if isMultiLine {
                x = 0.0
                y = thisRect.maxY + lineSpace
            }
            thisView.frame = thisRect
            // update the max width var
            newWidth = max(newWidth, thisRect.maxX)
            // if we did NOT need to wrap lines, adjust the X
            if !isMultiLine {
                x += sz.width + interItemSpace
            }
        }
        
        newHeight = thisRect.maxY
        
        if myWidth != newWidth || myHeight != newHeight {
            myWidth = newWidth
            myHeight = newHeight
            // don't activate the constraint if we're not in an auto-layout case
            if self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false {
                myHC.isActive = true
            }
            // update the height constraint constant
            myHC.constant = myHeight
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .init(width: myWidth, height: myHeight)
    }
    override func invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() {
        super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        
        // walk-up the view hierarchy...
        // this will handle self-sizing cells in a table or collection view, without
        //  the need to "call back" to the controller
        var sv = superview
        while sv != nil {
            if sv is UITableViewCell || sv is UICollectionViewCell {
                sv?.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
                sv = nil
            } else {
                sv = sv?.superview
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        willSet {
            if newValue.width != bounds.width {
                calcFrames(newValue.width)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

and a sample controller:
class BasicVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // sample strings
        let strs: [String] = [
            "MGLU3", "IBVV11", "BBSA3", "Slightly Longer String",
            "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT",
            "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE",
            "Hash Index Ethereum position replicated with a 100% accuracy",
            "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",
        ]

        let aView = BasicArrangedViewsView()
        
        aView.theStrings = strs
        
        aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(aView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            aView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            aView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            aView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // don't set a bottom or height constraint
        ])
        
        // so we can see the view frame
        aView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    
}

The result:

and how it looks implemented in your project:


That is an amazing solution, tks a lot!

@DonMag Could you please explain "Collection views are designed to layout the cells based on the frame - not the other way around."
How did you figure it out?

@PogosAnesyan - It's pretty much the fundamentals design and purpose of a UICollectionView.

@DonMag Could you reveal more, I don't quite understand you, cells are layout based on frame of what ?

@PogosAnesyan - I mean the frame of the collection view. With vertical flow layout and 28 cells, if your cells are 50x50 (with min 8-pt spacing), and your collection view frame is w: 200 h: 50 you will see one row of 3 cells (and you can scroll). If the frame is w: 300 h: 50 you will see one row of 5 cells. If the frame is w: 300 h: 500 you get 5 rows each with 5 cells and one row with 3 cells and "empty space" at the bottom. So the flow layout lays-out the cells within the collection view frame.
